# .net remoting over USB

Tags: .net, usb, remoting

Is it possible to control an app that exposes a .NET Remoting interface from a client connected via USB? How would I do that...a custom transport channel? Both client and server run on Windows platforms.

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: What is the client? How is it connected?

Comment: Client is a PC, server is an instrument with a PC in it. Standard USB host/device cable.

Comment: Jim you have a problem, because there is no .net remoting for handheld devices, only if you use a third party library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after [this here](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Connecting-Two-PCs-Using-a-USB-USB-Cable/248/2), it's just plain ol' TCP/IP :)

**Edit 13 April 2011 20:53 EEST**

I guess you could set a static IP on the server and a DHCP service to give automatic IP addresses to clients, however I saw your update that it's a standard host/device cable, which changes everything.

I am however still unable to understand how this will work, as Windows PCs can only be hosts, not devices (I may be wrong, but I'm certain Linux can support this - http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/). You may be better served with i.e. http://usblan.belcarra.com/p/usblan-deployment-guide.html and hand out installation CDs with your device, if you can configure Windows as a client (device).

Comment: Good link Vladislav to sustain your idea is similar with using ActiveSync in PC<=>Windows Mobile scenario. ActiveSync is assigning IPs and you can play with sockets and so on.

Comment: Exactly, no need to reinvent the channel.. ehm wheel

Comment: Cool. Not sure it will fly with the customer, though it is a completely reasonable solution. I presume you have to run some app on the client to discover what the IP address of the server is?

Comment: I provided an edit in the above answer, as it turned out to be pretty lengthy :)